# Returns an associative array comprising a function's argument list in php

Tags: php, associative-array, argument-passing

in php [**func_get_args**](https://www.php.net/func_get_args) — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list

it returns  ***numeric index array***

is there any function/way in php by which we get ***associative array*** i.e. key=>value pair

i m explaining with example:

###test.php

```
<?php

function foo() {
    include './fga.inc';
}
$x=20;
$y=30;

foo($x, $y);
?>
```

###fga.inc

```
<?php

$args = func_get_args();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($args);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

which should returns

```
array (
  'x'=> 20,
  'y' => 30,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this within your `foo()` function, because PHP doesn't pass the variable names to your function, only their values. Plus, PHP doesn't support named arguments in functions, [and it doesn't seem like it'll do so anytime soon](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#named-parameters).

A workaround would be to pass an associative array as a single argument to your function. You can use [`compact()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to collate the variables in the calling scope that you want to pass, for example:

```
function foo($args) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($args);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$x = 20;
$y = 30;

foo(compact('x', 'y'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [x] => 20
    [y] => 30
)
```